# running a function inside a package

Tags: r, data.table

I wrote a script that executes without a problem if I run it line-by-line, or if I execute it as a function, however when I put it inside a homemade package, and try to run it, it fails with this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
```

Which I don't really understand. If I do  `str()` of this data.table it looks like everything is the right type.

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  631 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ week_ending: Date, format: "1986-05-11" "1986-05-18" "1986-05-25" ...
 $ idx        : num  388 424 403 414 423 441 449 435 459 465 ...
 $ Year       : int  1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 1986 ...
 $ szWeek     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
NULL
```

This is the line of the function that fails (when placed inside the package):

```
newCond0[, .SD[max(szWeek) == szWeek], year(week_ending)]
```

Basically the question boils down to: is there any reason something would fail to run inside a package if it runs outside the packages?

Edit:

Running `search()` from inside the function (both inside and outside the package) gives slightly different results:

Inside (function fails)

```
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"            "devtools_shims"        "package:myPackage"
```

Outside (function executes)

```
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"            "package:myPackage" "devtools_shims"
```

After that the packages are identical.

Comment: Does your package import or depend on `data.table`? Are there other dependencies that might be missed?

Comment: How could I check this?

Comment: but the function / script runs outside the package if I load the package, and only the package... So it looks like all the necessary dependencies are included in the package.

Comment: I think you need to narrow down the problem and make a minimal reproducible example. You have a problem with 631 rows of data. Do you still have a problem with 100 rows of data? How about 5 rows of data? If you make another function that takes `newCond0` as an input just before that one line, and just tries to execute that line, does it work outside of the package? Inside the package? How many lines of code can you delete from you function and still have the problem?

Comment: @Gregor I tried making `newCond0` much smaller, no change. I edited my question and added the output of `search()`. Could `devtools_shims` being loaded before `myPackage` be the reason that this function is failing?

Comment: What is the content of your DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE files? Usually the problem is there.