# failure using data.table inside package function

Tags: r, data.table

I've done a package in R and included some `data.table` code inside my function:

```
ntalls[,.(NoMeas=sum(numer)),by=.(lance,esp,sexo,cate)]
```

`ntalls` is a `data.table`, and the code works fine as script when `data.table` is called in the workspace, but when I run the function inside the package I get:

> Error in .(NoMeas = sum(numer)) : could not find function "."

`data.table` is included in the DESCRIPTION of the library, and even loaded as `require(data.table)` inside the function. The package is built and compiled in Rstudio using R 3.5.0

How do I call `data.table::` inside the function?

Comment: Possibly relevant? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513319/data-table-error-could-not-find-function

Comment: Could you share the solution here? There is no definite answer highlighted over there.

Comment: I,ve found the solution in [running a function inside a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957777/) the solutions was to include depends `data.table` in `DESCRIPTION` file of the project. Thanks for the editions [mustaccio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227152/mustaccio)

Answer (score 5):

found the solution, or at least something that works:

including `depends` `data.table` in `DESCRIPTION` makes the package available so there's no need to use `require(data.table)` within the functions an the package works though it is much larger.

Comment: this works. `imports` doesn't help either unless `depends` is added